# Blender 3d printing solid objects instead of infilled objects

Tags: 3d-printing

When I go to print an object out of Blender to my Ender 2 V2 (my slicer is ultimaker cura 5.2.1), the void inside an object prints solid. For example, if I were to print a cube, it prints completely solid instead of infilling the inside space of the cube with just the simple angled infill structure. This of course results in my printed objects warping during printing and pulling off the printer and just ruining the print. Any suggestions? what do I need to do inside of blender in order to make the object have a custom thickness surface, then Infill instead of print solid

Comment: This issue is not Blender related hence I believe this one is off-topic. You have to check within the settings of your slicing software. Or you could manually 3d model the insides of your cube.

Comment: ...try the [Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) modifier to give the objects a wall thickness.

Comment: The object is most probably non-manifold. Use the 3D Print Toolbox to check it. This is a free addon that comes with Blender, you will need to activate it in preferences.